# How to understand 'all of which he pushes a baby stroller'

Tags: grammar

I have difficulty understanding the middle part of the sentence:

He carries just a tent, a sleeping bag and a few basic supplies, all of which he pushes a baby stroller, as he found that it requires less effort than carrying a backpack.

I know it's a relative clause, but is it grammatically correct?

Comment: I would bet good money that there is a missing word "in" before "a baby stroller"

Comment: @DJClayworth So true. It makes no sense without a preposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment says, the quote is probably missing the word *in*, inserted in bold here:

> He carries just a tent, a sleeping bag and a few basic supplies, all of which he pushes **in** a baby stroller, as he found that it requires less effort than carrying a backpack.

To clarify the sentence structure, the word **which** in *all of which* is a pronoun. Its antecedent is the list the sentence starts with (tent, sleeping bag, etc.)
So, it means that he pushes all of those things in a baby stroller.

Answer (score -1):

He carries just a tent, a sleeping bag and a few basic supplies, all of which put in a baby stroller he pushes, as he *finds* that it requires less effort than carrying a backpack.

He carries just a tent, a sleeping bag and a few basic supplies in a baby stroller he pushes, as he finds that it requires less effort than carrying a backpack.

He pushes a baby stroller carrying just a tent, a sleeping bag and a few basic supplies, as he *finds* that it requires less effort than carrying a backpack.